# Support chromecast in native iOS app

Tags: ios, chromecast, samsung-smart-tv

I have an iOS app which can play to apple TV using AirPlay. As I have heard that chrome cast extended the support to iOS how would I be abs to cast from my native iOS app to chrome cast so that video will be played in Google TV/Smart TV.

I have tried researching this in google however did not find any topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Cast SDK that you would use to discover Cast devices on your local network and then cast to them from your sender device (iOS, Android or Chrome device). You may or may not need to have your own receiver, which runs on the Chromecast; in most cases you don't need to have your own and can use the one that Google provides. Details are more than what can be summarized here but can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/developers). In addition, there is a number of [sample projects](http://github.com/googlecast) that you can also look at to see how the documentation works in a real application.

Comment: Just found that too..Looking at it..Thanks